# Access array from all Swift Files

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have an array stored in a class that downloads its objects from the internet. My class is set up like so:

```
class StockManager {
    var managerStock: [Dictionary<String, String>] {
        return downloadStockFromDatabase()
    }
    ...
}
```

I access the `managerStock` from other Swift files in my project like so, but it always resorts to re-downloading the stock again no matter if I have used the variable before (ie. recalls the function downloadStockFromDatabase):

```
let stockManager = StockManager()
print(stockManager.managerStock)
```

How would I make sure the `managerStock` only downloads once and I could use it in any of my files?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of correct software pattern usage. I would suggest:

- make StockManager a singleton, so you will always access the same instance of it
- initialize it e.g. in the AppDelegate, i.e. make sure it stays alive for the whole runtime
- tip: call managerStock lazily, i.e. only when you really need it and not as part of initialization

Answer (score 1):

As ff10 and holex suggested, make your class a singleton. It will look like this:

```
class StockManager {
    static let sharedInstance = StockManager ()
    var managerStock: [Dictionary<String, String>] {
        return downloadStockFromDatabase()
    }
    ...
}
```

Then access it using the static sharedInstance property:

```
print(StockManager.sharedInstance.managerStock)
```